# Java List of objects : Aggregation

Tags: java

I have a case where I need to aggregate a list of `Beans/Objects` to display their total characteristics. Let me explain my requirement first. I have a `List` of person details as shown :

```
    Person  Bank  Balance
    ---------------------
    Sam      GS   200
    Sam      JP   200
    Sam      WF   200
    John     GS   200
    John     JP   200
    Robin    JP   200
    Robin    JP   200
```

I want to aggregate the balances per person.

```
    Sam           700   <---- Key
    ------------------
        Sam      GS   200
        Sam      JP   300
        Sam      WF   200

    John          500   <---- Key
    ------------------
        John     GS   300
        John     JP   200

    Robin         200   <---- Key
    ------------------
        Robin    JP   100
        Robin    JP   100
```

Now, let's switch to what I have in my code - a `List` of such objects and I need to put them in a `Map`. The key would be the aggregated details, and its value will be the list of details. Here's my attempt, although its not that great:

```
public Map<Bean, List<Bean>> getAggregation(List<Bean> beans)
{
    Map<Bean, ArrayList<Bean>> aggreagtedBeans = new HashMap<Bean, new ArrayList<Bean>>();

    for(Bean bean : beans)
    {
        String name = bean.getName();
        boolean presentALready = false;
        Bean correspondingKey = null;
        for(Bean key :aggreagtedBeans.keySet())
        {
            if(key.getName().equals(name))
            {
                presentALready = true;
                correspondingKey = key;
                }
            }

            if(presentALready)
            {
                aggreagtedBeans.put(correspondingKey, aggreagtedBeans.get(correspondingKey).add(bean));
            }

            else
            {
                aggreagtedBeans.put(bean, aggreagtedBeans.get(correspondingKey).add(bean));
            }

        }
    return aggreagtedBeans;     
}
```

**Problems :**

Even with this `Map` approach, the key gets fixed and so am not able to update the balances as each row is added for a specific person.

**Limitations :**

I know this type of use case is ideal for database `order by` clauses, but I cannot use them. These are `Java Objects`.

Also, if you think that I should use a different data structure as per my use case, please suggest so, and if possible please provide a code snippet.

**EDIT :**

Attaching the `Bean` class code for reference :

```
public class Bean 
{
    String name;
    String bank;
    int balance;

    // constructors and getters
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't help myself since Java 8 is awesome:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    List<Bean> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Bean("John", 10));
    list.add(new Bean("Sam", 666));
    list.add(new Bean("Sam", 9));
    list.add(new Bean("John", 1));
    list.add(new Bean("John", 7));

    Map<String, Integer> sum = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Bean::getName, Collectors.summingInt(Bean::getBalance)));
    sum.entrySet().forEach(x -> list.add(new Bean(x.getKey(),x.getValue(), true)));
    list.sort((x,y) -> {
        int nameComp = x.getName().compareTo(y.getName());
        if (nameComp == 0)
            return x.isSum() ? -1 : 1;
        return nameComp;
    });
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
}

// Bean class with no "bank" variable, but with a new constructor and overloaded .toString()
static class Bean {
    private String name;
    private int balance;
    private final boolean isSum;

    Bean(String name, int balance, boolean isSum) {
        this.isSum = isSum;
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    Bean(String name, int balance) {
        this.isSum = false;
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getBalance() { return balance; }
    public boolean isSum() { return isSum; }
    @Override
    public String toString() { return name + " | " + balance + (isSum() ? " *Sum*" : ""); }
}
```

Output:

> John | 18 *Sum*
>
> John | 10
>
> John | 1
>
> John | 7
>
> Sam | 675 *Sum*
>
> Sam | 666
>
> Sam | 9

Comment: I haven't used Java 8, neither does my organisation. Looks good though :) :) Will make my life easier. Thanks a ton !!

Comment: If you want the sum-bean to be inside the list along with the others it's going to get ugly since they're not really on the same "level". One is an entry, other is a sum of entries. You can do it however (add a flag to the bean), and rather easily sort it too - Java 8 of course. Want the code?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to accumulate the balances is a

```
Map<String, Integer> name2balance = new HashMap<>();
```

A Bean is not a very good key in a map where you try to accumulate data for a person, as you have a 1:n relationship between name and Bean (name, bank, balance).

Especially with potentially volatile data (balance!) this may lead to trouble.

Answer (score 1):

public class JavTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Bean> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Bean("Sam", "GS",  200));
    list.add(new Bean("Sam", "JP",  300));
    list.add(new Bean("Sam", "WF",  200));
    list.add(new Bean("John", "GS",  300));
    list.add(new Bean("John", "JP",  200));
    list.add(new Bean("Robin", "JP",  100));
    list.add(new Bean("Robin", "JP",  100));


    HashMap<Bean, ArrayList<Bean> > beans = (HashMap<Bean, ArrayList<Bean>>) getAggregation(list);

    Set<Bean> sb = beans.keySet();

    for(Bean b : sb){
        System.out.println(b.getName() + " " + b.bank + " " + b.balance);
        for(Bean bb : beans.get(b)){
            System.out.println(bb.getName() + " " + bb.bank + " " + bb.balance);
        }
        System.out.println("---------------");
    }
}

public static Map<Bean, ArrayList<Bean>> getAggregation(List<Bean> beans)
{
    //ArrayList<Bean> al = new ArrayList<Bean>();
    HashMap<Bean, ArrayList<Bean> > aggreagtedBeans = new HashMap<Bean, ArrayList<Bean>>();

    for(Bean bean : beans)
    {

        String name = bean.getName();

        Set<Bean> keys = aggreagtedBeans.keySet();
        boolean found = false;
        Bean y = null;

        for(Bean x : keys){
            if(x.name == name){
                y = x;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(found == true){
            ArrayList<Bean> al = aggreagtedBeans.get(y);
            al.add(bean);

            Bean newBean = new Bean(y.name, bean.bank, y.balance + bean.balance);
            aggreagtedBeans.remove(y);

            aggreagtedBeans.put(newBean, al);               

        }else{

            ArrayList<Bean> tmp = new ArrayList<Bean>();
            tmp.add(bean);
            aggreagtedBeans.put(bean, tmp);
        }
    }



    return aggreagtedBeans;     
}
```

}

output :

Sam WF 700
Sam GS 200
Sam JP 300

### Sam WF 200

Robin JP 200
Robin JP 100

### Robin JP 100

John JP 500
John GS 300

### John JP 200

It should work , but it's not efficient to use Bean as key because every time you want to edit it you have to remove it *with its array list* then re-add them !

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this Assuming that one person can have only one account in one bank.

```
        int balOfSam = 0;
        int balOfJohn = 0;
        int balOfRobin = 0;
        for(Bean bean : list){
                map.put(bean.getName()+bean.getBank(),bean.getBalance());
        }
        Set<String> set = map.keySet();
        for(String key :set){
            if(key.startsWith("Sam"))
                balOfSam+=map.get(key);
            else if(key.startsWith("John"))
                balOfJohn+=map.get(key);
            else
                balOfRobin+=map.get(key);
        }
        System.out.println(balOfJohn);
        System.out.println(balOfSam);
        System.out.println(balOfRobin);
```

Comment: Well, Sam, John and Robin are just examples. I might have hundreds of such persons.

Comment: Ya it wil work if you have two similar names having same bank you need to associate some unique things to the key may be like accountno

Answer (score 1):

Using java 8:

```
List<Bean> allData = Arrays.asList(
    new Bean("Sam", "GS", 200),
    new Bean("Sam", "JP", 200),
    new Bean("Sam", "WF", 200),
    new Bean("John", "GS", 200),
    new Bean("John", "JP", 200),
    new Bean("Robin", "JP", 200),
    new Bean("Robin", "JP", 200)
);

allData.stream().collect(
        groupingBy(Bean::getName)
).forEach((name, dataForPerson) -> {   // dataForPerson is a List<Bean> for the name

    int totalForName = dataForPerson.stream()
            .mapToInt(Bean::getBalance)
            .sum(); 

    System.out.printf(       /* print header for each person */
            "%n%-14s%d%n-----------------%n", 
            name, 
            totalForName);

    dataForPerson.forEach(    /* print each entry for the person *//
            b->System.out.printf(
                    "%7s%5s%5s%n", 
                    b.getName(), 
                    b.getBank(), 
                    b.getBalance()
            )
    );      
});
```

Output:

```
John          400
-----------------
   John   GS  200
   John   JP  200

Robin         400
-----------------
  Robin   JP  200
  Robin   JP  200

Sam           600
-----------------
    Sam   GS  200
    Sam   JP  200
    Sam   WF  200
```